# Where are the human interface terms & conditions?

Tags: ios

The app store guidelines states:

"Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Apple iPhone Human Interface
Guidelines and the Apple iPad Human Interface Guidelines."

However there isn't a section nor any list of terms and conditions that I can see in the HIG document.

I'm trying to determine if there is a list of must-dos for apps from a GUI perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Human Interface Guidelines are just guidelines, they are not exact rules. There is not a list of must-dos but there are many recommendations, and best practices accumulated.

Comment: Exactly.  The word "must" is bogus, as there are lots of creative ways to make a good GUI, other than those specifically documented in the HIG, that Apple commonly (but not always) approves.

Comment: @hotpaw2 - Yes, this argument has been going on for years in the Mac development community, such as in articles like ["The HIG Is Dead. Long Live the HIG."](http://blog.maybeapps.com/post/2944393880/the-hig-is-dead-long-live-the-hig). The HIG is required reading, but well-thought-out custom UI controls that enhance the user experience are certainly welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Human Interface Principals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW1) and the [User Experience Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1). Apple wants you to put effort into your application. They do not want a bunch of developers just submitting an application that is just a wrapper around an HTML site for example. If you provide a custom icon, ease of usability, and a consistent user experience you will be fine.

Comment: As a side not, the recently released Xbox Live application by Microsoft is almost a completely custom UI that resembles the metro UI. This was approved because it meets the criteria I touched on above.

Comment: +1 (comments must be 15 chars)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the developer site? [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) Their documentation should be every iOS and Mac developer's first point of reference.